# Converting received ARKit pose to ROS pose

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm receiving ARKit's pose as is from iPhone and publishing in a topic. In ROS I need to convert it to the ROS reference frame.
ARKit is right-handed x-right, y-up and z-backward so my conversion is two rotations: -90 around X and -90 around Z.  However it does not give desired result in rviz.
Would appreciate pointing me in the right direction (practical/theoretical) to fix this.

ARKit -> ROS conversion:

```
tf::Pose convertCameraPoseToRos(const tf::Pose& cameraPose)
{
        // arkit to ros conversion
        // 1. rotate -90 around X
        // 2. rotate -90 around Z
        #define PI 3.1415926535897
        tf::Transform rotate1 = tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(tf::Vector3(1,0,0), -PI/2));
        tf::Transform rotate2 = tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(tf::Vector3(0,0,1), -PI/2));

        tf::Transform arCameraRotation = tf::Transform(cameraPose.getRotation());
        tf::Transform arCameraTranslation = tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(1,0,0,0), cameraPose.getOrigin());

    // tried this one - didn't work
        //return arCameraTranslation * rotate1 * rotate2 * arCameraRotation;
    
        return cameraPose * rotate1 * rotate2; // this one is current, but doesn't work either
}
```

ARKit pose obtaining on iOS in swift:

```
// inside delegate "func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)"
self.arKitT = frame.camera.transform 

arKitPose.position_.x_ = arKitT!.columns.3.x
arKitPose.position_.y_ = arKitT!.columns.3.y
arKitPose.position_.z_ = arKitT!.columns.3.z

let poseQ = simd_quatf(self.arKitT!)                    
arKitPose.rotation_.x_ = poseQ.vector.x
arKitPose.rotation_.y_ = poseQ.vector.y
arKitPose.rotation_.z_ = poseQ.vector.z
arKitPose.rotation_.w_ = poseQ.vector.w
// arKitPose is being published as PoseStamped
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401532/converting-received-arkit-pose-to-ros-pose/) by [peetonn](https://answers.ros.org/users/49640/peetonn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2022-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Didn't get my math correct -- needed to rotate -90 around Z, then -90 around Y. Also, the ordering should be different. In the end, this code worked for me:

```
    #define PI 3.1415926535897
    tf::Transform rotate1 = tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(tf::Vector3(0,1,0), -PI/2));
    tf::Transform rotate2 = tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(tf::Vector3(0,0,1), -PI/2));

    return rotate1 * rotate2 * cameraPose;
```

---

Originally posted by [peetonn](https://answers.ros.org/users/49640/peetonn/) with karma: 28 on 2022-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0